# Flutter&Dart: How to convert the result to Map and dynamic isn't contained _JsonMap?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

My code looks like this:

```
RxMap<String, String> menuDrink = RxMap<String, String>({}), menuFood = RxMap<String, String>({});

Map<String, dynamic> result = {
  'balance': 100,
  'menu': {
    'drink': {
      '1': 'menu 1',
      '2': 'menu 2',
      '3': 'menu 3',
    },
    'food': {
      '1': 'menu 1',
      '2': 'menu 2',
      '3': 'menu 3',
    }
  }
};

menuDrink.value = result['menu']['drink'];
menuFood.value = result['menu']['food'];
```

This works fine. But when I get the `result` from

```
Map<String, dynamic> result = json.decode(response);
```

It will error:

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'Map<String, String>', but got one of type '_JsonMap'
```

I have tried

```
Map result = json.decode(response) as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

But this type is still `_JsonMap`.

For using

```
Map result = Map<String,dynamic>.from(json.decode(response));
```

I got the `LinkedMap<dynamic, dynamic>` type.

Or create a new Map:

```
Map resultFormatted = {};
for (MapEntry element in (result ?? {}).entries) {
  resultFormatted[element.key] = element.value;
}
```

The `resultFormatted` isn't `_JsonMap` now, but the `Map` value inside still `_JsonMap`.

How to convert the result to Map<String, dynamic> and dynamic isn't contained _JsonMap? Is it possible?

At the moment, I've created a function that converts the `result['menu'][...]` to `Map<String,String>`.

Comment: how do you use your response? it seems your response is Map, no need to convert.

Comment: You shouldn't worry much about what the print says. You can just use it as a `Map<String, dynamic>` with the code you have now

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question. I've updated the question to make the issue easier to understand.